# what does # mean in printf() function? c programmers

Tags: c, printf

I was reading a multiplication table program source code and I encounter `#` sign in all of his `printf` functions that were printing decimal.

I played with the source code to see if it makes any difference, but everything seemed the same to me. what does # mean and why would he use it in `printf` function?

```
printf ("%#2d |", i);
```

Edit: I wanted to know why would this guy use `#` in `printf()` function for his multiplication table when he doesn't even need it.

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7392-multiplication-table-as-c-table#note

Everyone copy pasted from somewhere. not an answer to my question.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: This question could be improved by showing research, e.g. reference pages for printf to see what they actually say about this. And then come back here with the specific question if something is not clear.

Comment: and you better read the description and then comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Character**

#

**Description**

Alternate form. For 'g' and 'G', trailing zeros are not removed. For 'f', 'F', 'e', 'E', 'g', 'G', the output always contains a decimal point. For 'o', 'x', and 'X', a 0, 0x, and 0X, respectively, is prepended to non-zero numbers.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders

***EDIT***

To answer one of your other questions:

> edit: i wanted to know why would this guy use # in printf() function
>   for his multiplication table when he doesnt even need it.

Good question. gcc gives a warning:

> warning: '#' flag used with ‘%d’ gnu_printf format [-Wformat=]

You might have to ask the person who wrote the script, since we are not able to know what they were thinking when they wrote it, and we can't give you a definitive answer just guess.

Comment: my compiler doesnt give me any warning. anyways, thanks.

Comment: @user3621666 Yeah it depends what flags you have when you are compiling it. I compiled it with: `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall`. That way you get warnings and not just errors.

Comment: I use 'make'command inside vim which compile it this way "cc -myprogram.c -myprogram"
next time i compile your way so it will also give me warning.

Comment: @user3621666 Yes and you can modify the default make command inside Vim to add those flags for you, so you don't have to add them yourself. Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf

> Used with o, x or X specifiers the value is preceeded with 0, 0x or 0X respectively for values different than zero.
>
> Used with a, A, e, E, f, F, g or G it forces the written output to contain a decimal point even if no more digits follow. By default, if no digits follow, no decimal point is written.

It doesn't say anything about what what happens with `d` specifier.

Comment: if it used to print hexodecimals why this guy has it in his source code for multiplication table?
http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7392-multiplication-table-as-c-table#note

Comment: I don't know. Possible reasons: The `d` used to be `x` in the past. The particular compiler has some behavior that the programmer took advantage of. The format was copied and pasted from another place where `#` was useful.

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf (Section "The flag characters"), the result is undefined for the `d` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

**Seems to add conversional prefix or suffix.**  
Here is an example from wikipedia:

```
printf("Color %s, number1 %d, number2 %05d, hex %#x, float %5.2f, unsigned value %u.\n", "red", 123456, 89, 255, 3.14159, 250);
```

will print the following line (including new-line character, \n):

```
Color red, number1 123456, number2 00089, hex 0xff, float  3.14, unsigned value 250.
```

**you can also refer to 'man 3 printf', the following is an snapshot from it** 
#
The value should be converted to an "alternate form". For o conversions, the first character of the output string is made zero (by prefixing a 0 if it was not zero already). For x and X conversions, a nonzero result has the string "0x" (or "0X" for X conversions) prepended to it. For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the result will always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it (normally, a decimal point appears in the results of those conversions only if a digit follows). For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the result as they would otherwise be. For other conversions, the result is undefined.